# Typing non-English characters in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

I'm beginning to do a lot of typing in Spanish, and am hoping for a convenient way to use the few special characters (accented vowels, and the **ñ**) in a system-wide fashion.  I have used Spanish language keyboards before, which do the trick, but I'm not interested in changing keyboards every 5 minutes when I change language contexts.

As I recall, the Spanish keyboards accomplish the accent marks by essentially adding a new "shift"-type key, when pressed in combination with the vowel, it produces the accented version.

I've also seen macro set ups for OpenOffice.org, which essentially convert <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to **ó**.

I would be willing to use either a key combination, or two-key approach, the main requirement is that it needs to be system-wide (thus the OpenOffice.org macros aren't an acceptable solution).

What are my options?  Do I just need to get out a keyboard mapper and map some key combinations to my accented vowels?  I'm hoping for something a bit more standard than that, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the keyboard layout options and map <kbd>Compose</kbd> to a key (my personal preference is <kbd>Menu</kbd>). That way you can type <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>N</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> and get `ñ`, among many others.

> áè¡¿öîç¼™§«…—